# HEREmaps SDK Flutter - Routing error: 6, exception: These credentials do not authorize access, error code: 403

Tags: flutter, dart, heremaps

Im using Here SDK (Explore) for Flutter, the account got billinginformations and right credentials. I can show a map and draw polylines on it.

But when i try to add a Route it doesnt work with following error:

> E/routing ( 3234): [ERROR] routing - Routing error: 6, exception: These credentials do not >authorize access, error code: 403

the function to get the Route is the same from the examples:

```
    _routingEngine.importCarRoute(routeLocations, CarOptions.withDefaults(), (routingError, routes) {
      if (routingError == null) {
        here.Route route = routes!.first;
        _showRouteDetails(route);
        _showRouteOnMap(route);
        _logRouteSectionDetails(route);
        _logRouteViolations(route);
      } else {
        var error = routingError.toString();
        _showDialog('Error', 'Error while calculating a route: $error');
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your observation is correct. The official [release notes](https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.11.1.0/release_notes/topics/notes_navigate.html#version-41110) list this as known issue:

> **RoutingEngine**: The route import feature via a list of Locations cannot be used yet commercially and requires custom access credentials. Please contact your sales representative to get access.

I hope the HERE team can fix this soon. Until then, HERE needs to enable the credentials manually per customer. Ideally, contact the HERE team directly to get your credentials enabled for this feature.

Comment: Yeah there were some credential and account access problems on Here site. Contacted support and managed to get things right.

Comment: hi @Eric 
I have same problem, Can you help me what I should do to solve it

Comment: couldn't do anything beside contact HERE Support. You have to check your credentials with HERE Support. @MostafaMahmoud

Comment: And It runs after that or what?
also, was your subscription premium or just free?

Comment: yep cooperate partnership plan. But i think its the same as Premium.